# Not able to see complete XAML Source anymore

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, visual-studio-2022

I am working with Visual Studio 2022 on Windows 10, worked with all the previews and November 8 I upgraded to the release version. Until last Friday no problem.

This morning I openend my WPF Desktop project, opened a XAML page, the designer window was showing my Screen as expected, but I was not able to see my entire XAML source, Only a few rows, wit a lot of empty space jumping from line 1-2-4-7-24
[![enter image description here][1]][1]

I tried to disable the designer, checked if i could see any related settings, But whatever I tried no complete source in VS

I checked other XAML pages in my project, there I have the same problem
I checked the XAML in another editor and this is what the above picture should show
[![enter image description here][2]][2]

Then my last check, I created a new project with a WPF Template, with the same result, only part of the XAML Source is visible and i cannot get the entire XAML source

As far as I know I did not install anything on Friday neither was there an update. Som what have I done to "break" this, and how can I fix it. Almost sure it is something small and stupid "just hit that ... button in the toolbar" but simply can't find it.

Today I reinstalled vs 2022, but same problemen.

I know its not much info, but this is what I have

Hope anyone can help me with this.
Herbert
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Svs1M.png
[2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Kysdb.png

Answer (score 0):

Solved the problem, had also another machine without this problem and compared settings step by step.

Problem was That Adaptive formatting was turned on, turning it off again showed all of my code again.

Where to find this setting:
Tools\ Options \ Text Editor \ Advanced \ Use Adaptive Formatting